# Nested JSON in php

Tags: php, json

I do have problems with nested JSON array:

```
{
data: [
    {
        id: 630299,
        weather: null,
        .
        .
        .
        homeTeam: {
            id: 1384,
            name: "Tromsø",
            logo: "https://soccerama.pro/images/teams/NOR/1384.png",
            twitter: null,
            venue_id: 329,
            coach_id: 142585,
            chairman_id: null
        },
```

Here is my code:

```
$sy_json_match_cal=file_get_contents('url');
$sy_match_cal = json_decode($sy_json_match_cal,true);
$sy_match_calendar = $sy_match_cal['data']; 

foreach ($sy_match_calendar as $sy_objects) {

    $sy_match_id = $sy_objects['id'];
    $sy_hteam_id = $sy_objects['home_team_id'];
    $sy_ateam_id = $sy_objects['away_team_id'];
    $sy_kickoff = $sy_objects['starting_time'];
```

Those work great, but I have tried and googled a lot to get any results from the **homeTeam** data. No chance. This is what I tried (amongst others):

```
    $sy_hteam_name = $sy_objects['homeTeam'][0]['id'];
```

I have already checked and tried solutions from [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php), but that didn't make it any better. Would be awesome if you might have a solution for me. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry guys: solved! Thank you guys!